# Numlock light turns off when you switch language with super + space

Tags: 14.04, numlock

Whenever I switch languages from English to another, my Num Lock light turns off, though I still can use it. I'm aware that it's an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS bug. But are there any patches for it?

Comment: This bug also appears in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after login when using a non-English keyboard layout (even without any manual layout switching).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug report is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1247668). Egmont Koblinger wrote a [patch](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/174059708/xorg-server-xkb-numlock.patch) (see comment #22 of the bug report). I don't switch languages so I didn't test it, but other users have reported that it works.

[Download it](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/174059708/xorg-server-xkb-numlock.patch) and rebuild xorg-server using the following steps (as Egmont outlined in his comment):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev
mkdir build
cd build
apt-get source xorg-server
sudo apt-get build-dep xorg-server
cd xorg-server-1.15.1
cp ~/Downloads/xorg-server-xkb-numlock.patch debian/patches/ # replace Downloads appropriately
echo xorg-server-xkb-numlock.patch >> debian/patches/series
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i xserver-common_1.15.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb xserver-xorg-core_1.15.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

See also comment #27 of that report by dimitronic for an alternate method, though it's a script, not a patch as you requested. I've copied it below:

```
1)mkdir ~/keyfix ; cd ~/keyfix

2)open a file show_layout.sh and copy and paste this: " setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F"+" '{print $2}' " (without the first and the last ")

3)open a file keyfix.sh and copy and paste this:
s=0
s1=0
while test "1" == "1"
do

s=`$HOME/keyfix/show_layout.sh`

sleep 0.001s

if test "$s" != "$s1"
then

numlockx off
numlockx on

#if test "$s" == "alt_layout"
#then
#xset led named "Scroll Lock"
#else
#xset -led named "Scroll Lock"
#fi

fi

s1=`$HOME/keyfix/show_layout.sh`

if test "$s" != "$s1"
then

numlockx off
numlockx on

#if test "$s" == "alt_layout"
#then
#xset led named "Scroll Lock"
#else
#xset -led named "Scroll Lock"
#fi

fi
sleep 0.01s

done
********************
if you want to turn on scroll lock when you use alternative layout, remove the #'s and change alt_layout to your alternative layout i.e. "gr" or "us"
**************************

3)open a file disown_easy.sh and copy and paste this:
#!/bin/bash
$1 &
P=`which $1`
disown `pidof ${P}`

4)open a file run-keyfix and copy and paste this:
$HOME/keyfix/disown_easy.sh $HOME/keyfix/keyfix.sh

5) open a terminal and type:
 chmod +x ~/keyfix/* ; sudo cp ~/keyfix/run-keyfix /usr/bin/

6)make the script run-keyfix to run on startup! (go to startup applications and add it)

THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION! THIS IS A STUPID FIX!

*don't use these scripts to make weapons!
```

Comment: Thanks, do they plan to fix this annoying bug? I mean ubuntu team.

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, it seems like it's a problem with certain hardware manufacturers doing things weirdly. The bug was forwarded upstream, so if anyone would fix it it's the xorg developers. See:  https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78012