# NumLock wont activate on startup in 15.04

Tags: 15.04

I cant activate NumLock on startup in 15.04 procedure that always worked up to and including 14.04 NumLock is on in bios, then turns off during startup. Responds when NumLock pressed after startup, then NumLock light goes out.

Comment: Sounds like this bug: http://askubuntu.com/questions/509029/numlock-light-turns-off-when-you-switch-language-with-super-space

Answer (score 7):

Follow these instructions and you should be all set

Open a terminal

type:

```
sudo apt-get install -y numlockx
sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

Add this to the bottom of the script:

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

And you should be golden.

If numlock turns off after you login add `/usr/bin/numlockx on` to startup applications.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock for additional info if you need it